# Comprehensive reference for automata

Tags: automata, reference-request

I'm looking for a general reference cataloguing types of automata. Any introductory textbook will cover DFAs, NFAs, PDAs, and TMs, but there are countless more automata of practical or theoretical interest — linear bounded, embedded pushdown, nested stack, tagged finite, and so on. Online resources for these tend to be scattered.

Is there any sort of comprehensive reference, whether online or in print? Even incomplete surveys would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no list out on the web, nor even a partial list. I spent a few days looking and found nothing. The best you can do is piece together a list on your own (and post it here! :D).